# TF model input node not found in android

Tags: android, python, tensorflow

I trained a hair_recognition model(.pb file). It works fine with the python code. The input node is 'hair_recognition/input_1' But when I use the model in android, I get below error :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No Operation named [hair_recognition/input_1]
```

**I have debugged the models by printing node names in both Python & Android. But not able to figure out the cause.
Any suggestion on what could be causing this behaviour ?**

**code - loading model & fetching input tensor node**

**Python :**

```
 with tf.gfile.GFile(pb_file, "rb") as f:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())

    with tf.Graph().as_default() as ')graph:
        tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='hair_recognition')

 for op in graph.get_operations():
        print(op.name)

    x = graph.get_tensor_by_name('hair_recognition/input_1:0')
```

**Android :**

```
inferenceInterface.feed(
                INPUT_NODE, floatValues, 1, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), 3);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I myself have faced a similar problem earlier. 
The reason is you are loading the model in python with a prefix string - `hair_recognition`. So your input tensor has that name.
Change prefix to some other value like '.' or empty string. It should also work in that case.

In Android pass `input_1:0` instead of `hair_recognition/input_1:0` to `INPUT_NODE`. And the error should be resolved.